# Python Mockito: How do I mock open()

Tags: python, mocking

This is the code I want to test

```
file_handle = open('filename')
content = file_handle.read()
```

Now, in my test file, I want to mock `open()`

I tried using mockito when as below

```
when(open(...)).thenReturn(dummy_response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, which is not straightforward but works like a charm

```
import builtins

when(builtins).open(...).thenReturn(dummy_response)
```